# Click: Get original command as string

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm using the Click to build a command-line application. For audit purposes, need to get access full original command that the user executed. I had no luck getting the original user command before the Click parsing arguments. I couldn't find any similar use case in their documentation. something like :

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--debug/--no-debug', default=False)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, debug):
    if debug:
      # print('Original unparssed command with arguments')
```

I wanted to check if anyone knows a trick to get that before opening an issue on the github.

Comment: Your program never saw the complete command; the shell that it was launched from parsed it into individual parameters, which may involve removal of quoting, I/O redirection, etc.  The parameters are in `sys.argv`; you could do `" ".join(sys.argv)` to at least get an approximation of the original command line.  (I'm assuming here that Click doesn't modify that list, it's not a module I've ever used.)

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, yeah sys.argv contains what I've been looking for. I was looking into the parser module and totally forgot sys.argv still capturing those. please put it as an answer to mark it as a correct solution.